# Limits with two variables

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0.0)} \frac{xy\cos y}{3x^2+y^2}
$$

Approach along the path $x=0$, $y$ not $0$:

$$\frac{0}{3x^2}=0$$

Approach along $x=y$:

$$\frac{x^2\cos x}{4x^2}=\frac{\cos x}{4}$$

Therefore, it shouldn't exist as the limits are not the same. Is this approach / logic right?

(Also, how do I properly type up maths formatting? Is there some easy way to type in stuff like "3x/y^5" and it will automatically render the appropriately coded text?)

Comment: Yes, this is a good proof! For your second question, I don't think so since Latex is not that smart...

Comment: For simple fractions, you can use `{numerator} \over {denominator}`. For example, `3x \over y^5` produces $3x \over y^5$. For more complicated fractions, use `\frac{numerator}{denominator}`. The advantage with the first method is that if the expressions are simple enough, then you don't need to use braces.

Comment: Look at my edits to the question.  That should answer your question about typesetting. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is good. As for the second question, you have to use the \frac and $$ operator here.

As an example, you have to put the following code between \$\$ and \$\$

\frac{3x}{y^5}